# Can I change which branch a Git branch stems from?

Tags: git, version-control

In our project we have a develop branch, and whenever working on an issue, we branch from develop to item-xxxx and do our work there.

It seems that `item-0012` was branched off a commit from `item-0009` instead of the `develop` branch and pushed. So, a merge of `item-0012` back into develop would include changes for both branches.

Is there a way to get `item-0012` to go back to being branched off `develop`? There were no changes made in `item-0009` needed by `item-0012`.

Sorry if I'm missing the terms, still wrapping my head around Git.

Right now Git looks something like this with `item-0012` branched off of commit (c17) of the `item-0009` branch:
develop-(c14)-(c16)-(c18)
____\item-0009-(c15)-(c17)
____________________  \item-0012-(c20)

I would like the `item-0012` branch to stem off of commit (c16):
develop-(c14)-(c16)-(c18)
_____________  \item-0012-(c20)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to rebase your item-0012 onto develop? From rebase docs:

```
   Here is how you would transplant a topic branch based on one branch to another, to pretend that you forked the topic branch from the latter branch,
   using rebase --onto.

   First let's assume your topic is based on branch next. For example, a feature developed in topic depends on some functionality which is found in next.

           o---o---o---o---o  master
                \
                 o---o---o---o---o  next
                                  \
                                   o---o---o  topic

   We want to make topic forked from branch master; for example, because the functionality on which topic depends was merged into the more stable master
   branch. We want our tree to look like this:

           o---o---o---o---o  master
               |            \
               |             o'--o'--o'  topic
                \
                 o---o---o---o---o  next

   We can get this using the following command:

       git rebase --onto master next topic
```

You should `git rebase --onto develop item-0009 item-0012`

Comment: I'm rebased, Visual Studio says I have a bunch of commits to push. It seems like all the commits.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are still wrapping your head around git, I'll give a more general answer.

### Branches do not "stem" from each other

It is important to wrap your head around the fact that branches in `git` are not "first class citizens". They are nothing except small sticky notes that point to a specific commit. They can be moved around, created, deleted without changing anything in the actuall content of the repository. They do not count as "immutable history" like commits do.

They are nothing at all like branches in other systems (Subversion etc.), i.e., they are not heavyweight.

Especially, there is no sense at all to one branch somehow being the parent of another branch; branches have no relationship to anything at all except the single commit they point to. They are just an alias for the cryptic commit hashes, if you like.

### Rebase is your friend

`git rebase` does what you want. If you can, try to find out how with `git help rebase`, it has ASCII pictures and everything needed to get the necessary command line, so I won't cut&paste that stuff into this answer. It is worthwhile to do the head-around-wrapping with `git rebase` as well (i.e., studying the reference manual a.k.a. `git help rebase`) - you can do wondrous things with it and it is one of the killer features of `git`.